# Uncaught ReferenceError: setStatusClosed is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (index.html:1)

Tags: javascript, arrays, onclick, javascript-objects

I don't understand what is the problem here. Why does it show `setStatusClosed` is not defined?

```
     const fetchIssues = () => {
     const issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("issues"));
     const issuesList = document.getElementById("issuesList");
     issuesList.innerHTML = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) {
          const { id, description, severity, assignedTo, status } = issues[i];
          issuesList.innerHTML += `<div class="well">                              
          <a href="#" onclick="setStatusClosed(${id})" class="btn btn-warning">Close</a>                          
          </div>`;
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

**I'm trying to figure out this issue then I am successful

You can try it**
[enter link description here](https://google.com)

```js
const fetchIssues = () => {
  const issues = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("issues"));
  const issuesList = document.getElementById("issuesList");
  issuesList.innerHTML = "";
  let rIssue = issues.length;
  let tIssue = issues.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < issues.length; i++) {
    const { id, description, severity, assignedTo, status } = issues[i];
    if (status === "Closed") {
      rIssue = rIssue - 1;
    }

    issuesList.innerHTML += `<div class="well">
                              <h6>Issue ID: ${id} </h6>
                              <p><span class="label label-info ${
                                status === "Closed" ? "bg-danger" : ""
                              }" > ${status} </span></p>
                              <h3> ${
                                status === "Closed" ? "<strike>" : ""
                              } ${description} ${
                              status === "Closed" ? "</strike>" : ""
                              } </h3>
                              <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span>  ${severity}</p>
                              <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> ${assignedTo}</p>
                              <a href="#" onclick="closeIssue(${id})" class="btn btn-warning">Close</a>
                              <a href="#" onclick="deleteIssue(${id})" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                              </div>`;
  }
  document.getElementById("remaining-issue").innerText = rIssue;
  document.getElementById("total-issue").innerText = tIssue;
};
```

Comment: Please explain your solution. Answers which do not have an explanation and are only code get flagged as low effort.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: I'm working on a solution for past time and uploaded StackOverflow, so I don't know
That's how to explain.